# What makes air exist as a physical yet almost homogeneous mixture with no difference in concentration across regions?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, estimation, air, gas

You would think air being a physical mixture there would be changes in N2:O2 molar ratio across regions. But we all breathe more or less same composition of air, right? How come?

Comment: Molecular diffusion combined with small scale convection

Comment: Not N2:O2, but air in cars, occupied rooms, cities etc has measurable concentrations of CO2. Concentration gradients do exist.

Comment: How precisely are you measuring "more or less"? There's variation (in space & time) if you measure precisely enough. There's also isotopic variation.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/61140/why-dont-heavy-and-light-gases-separate-in-the-atmosphere explains it reasonably well.

Comment: Of course there are variations: the composition of air over a forest is not the same as that in downtown LA. But variations are not extreme because nature likes things mixed. For your question to have merit you must first look into what is the typical variation in the actual composition of air, and then formulate a more precise question.

Answer (score 1):

Air under the influence of gravity remains well-mixed because the kinetic energy of motion of the molecular species in it is greater than the gravitational potential energy difference between molecules at the top of a parcel of air and those at the bottom, where the distance between the top and the bottom of the parcel is of order ~mean free path length between collisions of those molecules.

Comment: Nice answer! Here is how the composition of the atmosphere varies on larger scales (of the order of ~10km and larger): https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/684414/226902

Answer (score -1):

I think that atmospheric pressure and temperature would help keep the displacement consistent. Like the thinning of oxygen in the atmosphere in Colorado, the concentration of certain molecules in any given place would be determined on the conditions of the atmosphere.

Also with the reaction of other molecules. Solar radiation from a CME can charge ozone molecules and cause them to combine with nitrogen, destroying the ozone and cause those molecules to move elsewhere in the atmosphere, increasing concentration of different molecules in different parts of the atmosphere.

Earth is pretty good at regulating itself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).